# .NET md5 doesn't equal md5sum.exe on unix

Tags: c#, .net, unix, md5

So I have an issue with comparing MD5 sums of the same text using the same techniques. I am using .NET MD5 tools and Unix's md5sum.exe program.

Here's my .NET code:

```cs
public void Test()
{
    string str1 = "testline1";
    string str2 = "testline2";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(str1);
    sb.Append(Constants.vbLf);
    sb.Append(str2);

    string hash = GetMD5Hash(sb.ToString());

    //hash = 4fb435ffb8e071151c3411dd3a922460
}

public string GetMD5Hash(string text)
{
    byte[] hash;
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I have a server running a unix based OS which has md5sum.exe on it. On my server I have a file which is simply:

```
testline1
testline2
```

Let's say the file is named testFile.txt

I have tried running multiple variations of md5sum to see if I can get these values to equal to no avail.

```
$md5sum testFile.txt                     //22f877bcf8985a0f038a5b70086b955d
$echo -n $(cat testFile.txt) | md5sum    //1e192bb9877cc2f20e7010d499c0a306
$echo -E $(cat testFile.txt) | md5sum    //83b6873b79ca36952eb58ea05083c02e

$unix2dos testFile.txt  //converting file to dos just in case line endings are issue
$md5sum testFile.txt                     //d302436fa25c7faaab75ceca1f1df16d
$echo -n $(cat testFile.txt) | md5sum    //94f0c8f7e9820cb6eda9e911ee21b2a8
$echo -E $(cat testFile.txt) | md5sum    //f39452a70621ed225057073e86f17858
```

I have worked at this for hours and cannot seem to get these MD5 to match. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your testFile.txt has a newline at the end of the second line, whereas your .NET code is not putting a newline at the end of the second line. If you run your file through `xxd`, you'll be able to see the extra newline that's tripping you up.

Comment: I re-created your testFile.txt to double-check. MD5 sum of testFile.txt with a single newline (0x0A) character at the end of both lines: 22f877bcf8985a0f038a5b70086b955d, just like you're getting when you run the command-line commands. MD5 sum of testFile.txt with the final newline stripped: 4fb435ffb8e071151c3411dd3a922460, just like your .NET code is producing.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the different line-breaks on each OS.

See here for how to convert one of those files to match the other's line breaks, and I bet your checksums will then match: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had taken line ending's into account. I learned Unix end's it's line in line feed's only which is why I appended just a vbLf instead of vbCrLf. I really appreciate it though.

Answer (score 0):

`echo -n "root" | md5sum`

The problem is newline, when to get the result in terminal, if you don't use `-n`, the result is wrong.

`-n     do not output the trailing newline`